# Calling pick results in "No Sampler was constructed"

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks,

I am trying to get a simple pick & place demo to work. Objects were added to the planning scene and are correctly shown in rviz with their according names. I am using the Franka Emika Panda simulation which is started with `roslaunch panda_moveit_config demo.launch`. When I use the `panda_arm_hand` planning group and call `group.pick('my_object')`, an error is displayed stating that "No sampler was constructed". In addition, maybe as a consequence of the above, the following appears in the log:

```
[ INFO] [1527240082.156847614]: Planning attempt 1 of at most 1
[ INFO] [1527240082.156979205]: Added plan for pipeline 'pick'. Queue is now of size 1
[ERROR] [1527240082.157460490]: No sampler was constructed
[ INFO] [1527240082.157499970]: Manipulation plan 0 failed at stage 'reachable & valid pose filter' on thread 0
[ WARN] [1527240082.158674635]: All supplied grasps failed. Retrying last grasp in verbose mode.
[ INFO] [1527240082.158787599]: Re-added last failed plan for pipeline 'pick'. Queue is now of size 1
[ INFO] [1527240082.159718144]: Manipulation plan 0 failed at stage 'reachable & valid pose filter' on thread 1
[ INFO] [1527240082.162419179]: Pickup planning completed after 0.001770 seconds
```

In another attempt, I supplied a list of possible (more or less meaningful) grasps to the pick method, but that didn't change the outcome.

Do you have any suggestion to get rid of this error message? I was unable to find any clue regarding this particular error message- Do I have to load any special package, configuration parameter, or must some ros node be running I am currently not aware of?

Some remarks: I work with an Rviz simulation primarily, Kinetic inside an Xenial-based Docker container. However, I observed the error message also with a real robot on a real Xenial Ubuntu System. Both Ros and Ubuntu Packages are up-tot-date. The controller invoking the pick routine is written in Python, if that matters.

Regards, SC

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292280/calling-pick-results-in-%22no-sampler-was-constructed%22/) by [SC](https://answers.ros.org/users/35455/sc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2018-05-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Replying to myself: The problem was an outdated/erroneous MoveIt configuration for the robot. Details can be found here: https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/948

---

Originally posted by [SC](https://answers.ros.org/users/35455/sc/) with karma: 36 on 2018-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1